# Issue when using a package (pagseguro/php) with composer in a laravel app, apparently it is not loading or initializing itself

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have a laravel app and i want to use the pagseguro/php package.
 I added it to the composer.json and updated. I can access the main class (PagSeguroPaymentRequest) without a problem.

At some point I have to call this:

```
PagSeguroConfig::getAccountCredentials();
```

But it throws an exception. After reading code around I thought on trying to init the library by myself and suddenly everything worked:

```
PagSeguroLibrary::init();
```

This method is inside the only php file in source/PagSeguroLibrary/

Shouldn't composer automatically execute this method? What is exactly "loading" a package? Is there anyway to fix this using composer only?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't composer automatically execute this method?

No, it shouldn't.  Composer is a package and dependency manager program. It's job is to

1. Get PHP files into your vendor folder
2. If using those PHP files means you need other PHP files, get those other PHP files into your vendor folder
3. Setup things so that class files from the packages are correctly autoloaded in PHP (i.e. no need to require or include stuff yourself)

Composer packages work independent of frameworks.  Someone could distribute a laravel service provider via a computer package, or someone could distribute code that doesn't know anything about Laravel.  How each composer package works is up to the author (always read the README)

In the case of `pagseguro/php`, it looks like you're supposed to instantiate a `PagSeguroPaymentRequest` object which, when autoloaded, will automatically call `init`.  The [examples distributed with the package](https://github.com/pagseguro/php/tree/master/source/examples) also makes it look like this package was code that predated composer, and still uses many manual includes and requires.

Comment: Yeah, it is kind of old. I'll fork and pull a fix for my issue. Does composer call ANY method of the classes it loads? I've seen some register methods that are magically loaded. Thanks.

Comment: @polar that might be custom plugins or installers.  https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md  There's also the ability to run scripts during certain parts of the composer life-cycle https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

Comment: All Composer does is the autoload part. It automatically includes the code that is needed to use a class. It does not configure anything the application is supposed to do to make things run.